# Allowing Multiple Cors In Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm trying to allow multiple cors with node in my express api, I've been able to get it to work but am currently facing two issues.

1. I can't connect to my api using postman because I checked and it turns out the origin sent from postman is undefined.
2. I have a mobile app which also communicate with the server, the issue is after I allowed multiple specific origin, the app also can't communicate with the server.

How do I solve this issue, because I can't leave my api server open to allow communication from every origin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [Cors for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Add the dependency:

```
$ npm install cors --save
```

And then add cors to your app.js

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 0):

On production try this instead of * on Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, For development allow any source will not be a problem (depend on your scenario)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "yourdomain.com");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers','Content-Type,expire');
next();
});
```

Try this one in your server. If you want to pass extra header parameter you need to add those variable in res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type , token'); but remember don't user '-' in the variable name.